# pandas to_csv() writes incorrect float values obtained by read_excel()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, floating-point

I use this code to convert xlsx to csv (I also tried `pd.read_excel(xlsx_filename, dtype=object)` and `pd.read_excel(xlsx_filename, converters={'my column':str})`):

```
data_xls = pd.read_excel(xlsx_filename, dtype={"my column": object})
data_xls.to_csv(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8')
```

When I open the xlsx file using Excel I see that the value in the field is `0.018311943169191`.
But when I open the csv file converted from that xlsx file by pandas I see value is `0.018311943169191037`.

So how to fix that? I mean how to have the same value in the converted csv as it was in original xlsx file?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA4K3.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xlsx viewer (Excel), there is a limit of precision 15 that's why you are seeing `0.018311943169191` instead of `0.018311943169191037`. This is not related to pandas to_csv().

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I extracted xlsx file using 7zip and got convinced that the value stored is 1.8311943169191037E-2 which is 0.018311943169191037.

Answer (score 0):

In the to_csv() function, you can modify the format of floating point numbers using [presentation formats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Given that the number in the Excel file has 15 digits to the right of the decimal, you could specify that you want all floats to have 15 digits to the right using the ***f*** presentation format in the to_csv() function. Please note that the below code would input **trailing zeros** for floats that have **less than 15 digits to the right** of the decimal point.

```
data_xls.to_csv(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8', float_format='%.15f')
```

If you want to set a maximum of number of digits after the decimal points, use the ***g*** presentation format instead. This sets a maximum number of 15 digits to the right of the decimal, but allows digits to the right of the decimal less than 15 **without the inclusion of trailing zeros**.

```
data_xls.to_csv(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8', float_format='%.15g')
```